# Create generic .Any extention method for IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the next models:

```
public class MaterialCatalog
    {
    public int MaterialCatalogID { get; set; }
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string MaterialName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MaterialCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    }

public class MaterialCategory
    {
        public int MaterialCatalogID { get; set; }
        public int UserCategoryID { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to create IQueryable generic external method for this code:

```
var items = (from l in ctx.WorkareaTemplates
                                where l.WorkareaTemplateCategories.Any(mc => mc.UserCategoryID == req.Category)
```

Here what I have tried. I get an error "The double operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[MaterialCategory]' and 'System.Int32'." How can I go to the subProperty to work with MaterialCategory

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> FilterByUserCategoryId<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, object searchValue)
    {
        if(typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Any(x => x.Name == "Categories"))
        { 
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "e");
                var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, "Categories");
                var value = Expression.Constant(searchValue);
                var body = Expression.Equal(prop, value);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, parameter);

                var overload = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
                var orderByGeneric = overload.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), prop.Type);

                var result = orderByGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });

                return (IQueryable<TSource>)result;
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: `I need to create IQueryable generic external method` what have you tried, what isn't working? Please update your post to include these details so we can help.

Comment: I think you might be looking in the wrong place - your where is what you want, but I think the issue is in how you have defined the body of your lambda?

Comment: @Trevor I have updated request, here is the exception